# How can the time to access an element of an associative array be independent of the number of elements in that array?

Tags: arrays, awk

I am currently making my first noteworthy awk script (specifically, gawk). Naturally, there were many questions, so I read most of its manual and stumbled across [the following statement](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Array-Intro.html#Array-Intro):

> awk’s arrays are efficient—the time to access an element is
>   independent of the number of elements in the array.

How does gawk achieve this, given that its arrays are associative and the array indices are strings?

Even if they are hashing the actual index values, those hashes still would have to be stored in appropriate data structures like binary trees etc., where the access time is not independent of the number of elements.

I could read the source code trying to understand how it is done, but I doubt that I would completely understand this in a reasonable time. So I am hoping that somebody could shortly explain the underlying technique or provide a reference.

Comment: I'm not well versed in algorithms, but I think accessing elements for hashes is `O(1)` .. https://greenteapress.com/thinkpython2/html/thinkpython2022.html#sec255 might help

Comment: Thank you very much for that link. I have studied it, and as I understand it, the algorithm that guy gives actually does not prevent all key-value pairs from being stored in the same `LinearTable` (it is very unlikely, but theoretically could happen). If this occurs, access time is O(n). Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: Yes, you can use LinearTable for associative arrays. It might be proper solution when the table access time is not critical (very small number of elements, infrequent access). The  upside is little storage overhead (vs regular has tables).

Comment: @dash-o There might be a misunderstanding. I was referring to the specific code in the link Sundeep has given. That hash table claims to provide constant access time, while I believe that under very, special circumstances it can only provide O(n) access time.

Comment: That's a known issue with poorly designed hash table data structures and hash functions, yes. A common mitigation is to incorporate some secret random value chosen at initialization time into the hash function to make it harder for an attacker to create keys that all hash to the same value. Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_hashing

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll study this.

Comment: Between this and your other question, I think a class or book on fundamental data structures like hash tables and binary trees would be very helpful.

Comment: Eventually yes, eventually, no :-) I know binary trees quite well, and I'm sure that they don't provide constant access time. Regarding hash tables, some (basic) articles like the one Sundeep linked got me the impression that "constant access time" is questionable. But indeed I haven't read much literature about measures against non-uniform hash distributions yet;